# “How can to fix the problem ‘ number_format error

Tags: php

I would like to shorten the result. I have used nummber_format but always an error appears.Can someone help me.

```
$arr = array();
    foreach ($order->orderPositions as $tax) {
        $arr[] = $tax->tax;
    }
    $unique_data = array_unique($arr);
    foreach ($unique_data as $val) {
        $totalTaxes[$val] = $order->orderPositions->where('tax', 
      $val)->sum('TotalPriceWithTax');
    }


  /*help is needed here*/  number_format((float)$unique_data,2);
```

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: I don't think `number_format` accepts array as parameter.

Comment: this is the Result from the array (18.181818181818)(15.966386554622)(1.3084112149533)

Comment: You need to loop the array and number format it

Comment: this is the Result from the array (18.181818181818)(15.966386554622)(1.3084112149533) <---- i want to shorten/reduce the numbers after the decimal point

Comment: @KenanHj  do you want to format `$totalTaxes[$val]` inside `foreach()` or you want to actually format `$unique_data` array? Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop the array and save them as the new format either in a new array or the same

```
$unique_data = array_unique($arr);
foreach ($unique_data as &$val) { //notice the & if you want to change the data points in the unique array
    $totalTaxes[$val] = $order->orderPositions->where('tax', $val)->sum('TotalPriceWithTax');
    $val = number_format($val,2); // replaces the data in unique array
    $new[] = number_format($val,2); // add to new array if you need unique array

}
```